# Number of proofs for a statement

Tags: proof-theory

On this site, people ask questions and then answers and proofs for those answers come from readers.  Readers mark the best answer and then people focus on the next interesting topic.  Sometimes, a question will have many answers with proofs from different points of view and people commenting on whether the proofs are valid or not.

My question is this, "given a statement, how many valid proofs are there for that statement?"  For example, if one is interested in the irrationality of root two there are many proofs available, all equally valid, some longer than others, some requiring basic math skills, others requiring in-depth knowledge.  We have a proof for Fermat's last theorem, but how many other proofs are there?  Is it possible to look at a statement and know that it has a finite number of proofs or an unlimited number?

Comment: In the formal sense, there are always infinitely many proofs, if there is one. Whether there are infinitely many essentially distinct proofs, whatever that may mean, is not clear.

Comment: Godel's Theorems may have application here.

Comment: For some statements, it is not even possible to prove them or disprove them.

Comment: An older post: [How many different proofs can a theorem have?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36975/how-many-different-proofs-can-a-theorem-have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a formal (in normal systems) sense the number of proofs are either 0 or countably infinite, and both cases are possible.

The first case is of course possible because there ought to be false statements that consequently should not be provable. But also there may exist undecidable statements (by Gödels Theorem), that is statements $p$ where there exists no proof for neither $p$ nor $\neg p$. Note that according to Gödel a system complete enough will have undecidable statements or contradictions (that means that statements known to be false will be provable).

For the case where proof exists they are countably infinite because for each formal proof you can always put in junk into the proof to generate a new proof.

The way you can prove this is that if you repeat your proof (verbatim) it's still a valid proof, and you can do that any number of times. So they are at least countably infinite.

That there are no more than countably infinite correct proofs follows of the facts that there are no more than countably infinite sequences of statements that could make up a proof (or be invalid as proof). A proof consists of a sequence of symbols from a finite alphabet and these sequences can be enumerated: for each length (being a natural number) we have finite number of sequences to add to the enumeration, so you can sequence them by starting with the empty sequence followed by the finite number of sequences of length one, and then the sequences of length two and so on (then every sequence will be included in the enumeration).

As for deciding which case that applies to a statement I'm not sure, but even for that question Gödels Theorem might apply (that would mean that there are statements for which you cannot decide whether there exists a proof for or against). In that case the only thing you could know is that if you proven it to be unprovable then you know or if you proven it to be provable then you know.

Note: some of this only applies to normal systems, one could for example construct a system where the method of constructing new proofs would result in a disallowed proof. Fx a proof is normally a sequence of statements according to some rules, but the above construction forms new by repeating the same statements over and over - in a system that disallow repeating a statement in a proof this method would only produce invalid proofs.

Comment: Ok, so for Fermat's last theorem (or any other) there are infinitely many valid proofs.  By valid I mean that they would be accepted as proving the theorem.  So, it's either 0 or countably infinite?  No in between?  So there is no such thing as a statement that has a finite number of proofs?  Say root 2 has only 500 proofs and we haven't discovered all of them yet, but once we do, there is no point in looking further.

Comment: When you say "construct a system..." you mean a system of math different from the one we currently use?

Comment: @michael_timofeev Not so much different. For example in a book by Cohen (IIRC) the inference rules included truth tables for proposition calculus. But since a truth table is enough to decide any statement of proposition calculus one could require that a valid proof of that should contain just a truth table and then conclude the statement as being true, then you have statements that have finite numbers of proofs, but a system that is essentially the same as the one we currently use. Then of course there is not only **one** system we have.

Answer (score 0):

I know of one book that contains 256 proofs of the Pythagoran theorem.

Wikipedia claims that several hundred proofs of the law of quadratic reciprocity have been found.

I am sure that there are limits. Especially within a strictly formal logical/mathematical system. But I don't think that the answer is simple.